# OLS regression interpretation when sample means from t-test are insignificant

Tags: statistical-significance, least-squares, mean

I tried to search for this somewhat basic question but was unable to find an exact answer. I am running a multiple regression model for time series data using OLS. The dependent variables seem to be insignificant based on a simple t-test where I have corrected the standard errors using Newey-West method. However, when I estimate my multiple regression model (also using robust standard errors), two out of the three independent variables have statistically significant effect on the LHS variable while the intercept remains insignificant (as it probably should be, based on the results of the t-test).

Is there an interpretation for this? I mean, if the LHS variable cannot be distinguished from zero under the usual OLS assumptions and certain confidence level, how are the RHS variables able to explain the changes in the LHS variable? Am I thinking this too hard or missing something obvious? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you mean with the dependent variable seems insignificant based on a t-test? Have you performed a one-sample t-test of the DV to test if its mean is significantly different from zero? If yes: what was the goal of this test?

Comment: That is exactly what I've done. The dependent variable is returns from a certain investment strategy and the point of the rest of my analysis is to see whether these returns are compensations for some other risk an investor might have taken, the measures for these are the RHS variables in the full model. If the sample means from t-tests are insignificant, I'm not sure if the intercepts in the regressions can be significant themselves, which is what I am ultimately concerned on. The t-tests were part of descriptive statistics I checked and I struggled to interpret the results.